# Como ordenar las filas de una columna con Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, datatables, ordenamiento

a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo cambios en una aplicación web que esta hecha con PHP, HTML, javascript y usa el framework Bootstrap.

En una parte de la aplicación se muestra una tabla con datos, y cada columna se puede ordenar según el campo de esa columna, por ejemplo en una de las columnas es "Prioridad". Como la aplicación ya estaba hecha, yo ahora tengo que modificar una cosa para que me muestre de manera ordenada la columna prioridad que tiene varios valores: Critica, Alta, Media y Baja.

El problema es que no logro averiguar porque no me ordena correctamente esa columna. Debería ordenarse como Critica, Alta, Media y Baja, pero no lo hace. Parece que la ordena alfabéticamente pero tampoco. Para la tabla usa Bootstrap pero supongo que el código de los plugins no se toca.

En el fichero php donde esta la tabla no hay nada referente al orden, no hay ninguna función js que haga algo para ordenar, así que por defecto lo hace el plugin de bootstrap.

la tabla en HTML esta (no pongo todo el contenido porque no tiene relación, aparte de porque es muy extenso):

```
 <table id="example-7" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Proyecto</th>
                <th class="text-center">ID Solicitud</th>
                <th class="text-center">Etiqueta</th>
                <th class="text-center">Prioridad</th>
```

y luego la columna Prioridad es esta (mezcla PHP con HTML, pero aquí tampoco hay nada referente al orden. Aqui recoge el dato de prioridad de la bbdd y lo pinta.):

```
                <?
                if($row['id_prioridad'] == "1"){
                ?>
                <td  class="text-center"><span class="label label-success" style="background-color:#9a9a9a">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<? echo $row['prioridad'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                <?}else if($row['id_prioridad'] == "2"){?>
                <td  class="text-center"><span class="label label-warning">&nbsp;&nbsp;<? echo $row['prioridad'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
                <?}else if($row['id_prioridad'] == "3"){?>
                <td  class="text-center"><span class="label label-danger">&nbsp;&nbsp; <? echo $row['prioridad'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>                   
                <?}else if($row['id_prioridad'] == "4"){?>
                <td  class="text-center"><span class="label label-success" style="background-color:#8317a8">&nbsp;<? echo $row['prioridad'];?>&nbsp;</span></td>
                <?}?>
```

Y por último aquí es donde importa el plugin de Bootstrap que se encarga de las tablas:

```
<!-- DataTables-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js</script>
```

Aparte de esto, no hay nada más, ni funciones dentro del fichero php, ni algo más que se encargue del orden de las filas de la tabla.

No se si alguien tiene alguna idea de bootstrap y como se podría hacer. Si modificando el código en los plugin, si añadiendo una función al fichero php...

Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos